# CG equivalent of texelFetchOffset

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, cg-language

What would be the `CG` equivalent of the `GLSL` function `texelFetchOffset`?

Comment: What do you mean by CG? Core Graphics?

Comment: The CG shading language, by NVidia.

Comment: Found an answer to my question. tex2Dlod has an optional parameter to specify the offset.

Comment: @user1757253 Are you sure `tex2Dlod` expects integer texel coordinates and doesn't do any filtering (like the GLSL `texelFetch` functions)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [nVidia documentation](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/Cg/tex2Dfetch.html):

`tex2Dfetch` - performs an unfiltered texture lookup in a given sampler.

Use one of these overloads:

```
float4 tex2Dfetch(sampler2D samp, int4 s)
float4 tex2Dfetch(sampler2D samp, int4 s, int texelOff)

int4 tex2Dfetch(isampler2D samp, int4 s)
int4 tex2Dfetch(isampler2D samp, int4 s, int texelOff)

unsigned int4 tex2Dfetch(usampler2D samp, int4 s)
unsigned int4 tex2Dfetch(usampler2D samp, int4 s, int texelOff)
```

Parameters

```
samp
    Sampler to lookup. 
s
    Coordinates to perform the lookup. 
    The level of detail is stored in the last component of the coordinate vector. 
texelOff
    Offset to be added to obtain the final texel.
```

Comment: Those functions rather look like they expect floating point texture coordinates in [0,1] and perform filtering, whereas the GLSL `texelFetch` functions expect dicrete integer texel positions and don't perform any filtering.